# Android: achartEngine with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine

I'm trying to integrate a graphs in an application I'm building, but I met a lot of difficulties when I try to integrate elements from achartEngine in fragments.

I found here a few discussions on the subject but no one helped me (such [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304489/how-to-use-chart-inside-fragment-in-android-using-achartengine-library) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290581/calling-acharengine-inside-fragment)).

Can anyone help or give direction?

---

Jackyto, This is my code according to your recommendation, but still not working for me (crash). : (

Thanks a lot!

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment {

private GraphicalView mChart;

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;

private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

LinearLayout layout;

private void initChart() {
    mCurrentSeries = new XYSeries("Sample Data");
    mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
    mCurrentRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mCurrentRenderer);
}

private void addSampleData() {
    mCurrentSeries.add(1, 2);
    mCurrentSeries.add(2, 3);
    mCurrentSeries.add(3, 2);
    mCurrentSeries.add(4, 5);
    mCurrentSeries.add(5, 4);
}

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();  

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);
    layout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    return root;
}

 public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mChart == null) {
            initChart();
            addSampleData();
            mChart = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(getActivity(), mDataset, mRenderer, 0.3f);
            layout.addView(mChart);
        } else {
            mChart.repaint();
        }
    }
```

}

Of course, I was define -  android: id = "@ + id / chart" in my layout.

Comment: Do you have a particular problem or you just can't see how to do that?

Comment: I am looking for a clear example to explain how to do it or something like that, I tried to build one myself, based on what I found online but it's not that simple. : (

Thank you.

Comment: Try here : http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/achartengine-charting-library-for.html . Then i just put my chart layout into my Fragment layout and it was done. If you have any question :)

Comment: Or this: http://jaxenter.com/effort-free-graphs-on-android-with-achartengine-46199.html

Comment: Jackyto, I updated the question in accordance with the code you gave me, but still it doesn't work. :( Dan, I don't understand where to look in the link you gave me.

Comment: layout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.chart); this line must be within onResume() function.

Comment: I cant.... I got "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type LayoutOne" when I do that.

Comment: and when I define field "root" before and to that - the program crash.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in onActivityCreated

```
 initChart();
 addSampleData();
 mChart = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(getActivity(), mDataset, mRenderer, 0.3f);
 layout.addView(mChart);`
```